# How to set the size of the window in GNU Screen in Linux

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I am a new user of GNU Screen.  I'm trying to launch a GNU Screen window with a pre-specified number of rows and columns.  I am running Red Hat Linux where the command "xterm" is not implemented.  So far I've learned that a file called .screenrc located in my home directory controls many aspects of the window that is created, and sample commands that I've put in it are indeed reflected in the window that is created, however, after more than a week of searching I have not been able to find anything on the Internet that shows the commands to place in the .screenrc file that will cause it to pop up with a particular size, i.e. a particular number of rows and columns.  The only advice I was given was to include the instruction defscrollback number-of-lines in my .screenrc file, but that isn't working for me.  Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> after more than a week of searching I have not been able to find anything on the Internet that shows the commands to place in the .screenrc file that will cause it to pop up with a particular size, i.e. a particular number of rows and columns

That's because the windows you are seeing **are not** GNU Screen windows. Screen is only a "proxy" terminal emulator – it does not have the *ability* to pop up GUI windows all by itself; it *always* renders inside another terminal emulator app, whether it's Xterm or something else.

Even if you launch it through the GUI environment's app menu, it just gets launched together with whichever default terminal emulator app your environment uses.

While Xterm is the "original", there are dozens of terminal emulators that might be installed on your RH(E?)L system; most likely I suspect you have GNOME Terminal, with the `gnome-terminal` command. To change its dimensions, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-right-click the terminal area and choose "Preferences > Profiles > Default > Size".

`pstree -Th` might give you more hints as to what terminal emulator app you're using.

Comment: Hi user1686, thanks for this information.  I've found that not only is xterm not implemented on my system, neither is Konsole nor Gnome.  I explored the output of the pstree command but could not identify the terminal emulator in use.  At this point I'm willing to forgo the use of screen and work with any command that I can issue at the command prompt that will open a new window, but so far have not found anything.  Anyway, thanks for your reply, I learned a few new things from it.